# Text aspect JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

I whant to know what properties is to make text to have the same aspect like in console or how can I make the text to have the same aspect like in console ?

this is the output from console:

[image]

This is the output from my interface:

[image]

Comment: Change the JTextArea's Font to Font.MONOSPACED. e.g., `myTextArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));` This will allow the characters to line up correctly.

Comment: Suggestion: add a [tag:swing] tag to your question to get the Swing experts in to see it. My reputation is too low to do this for you, and the suggested edit queue is full.

Comment: thanks for sugestion @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JTextArea is using a Font that is not monospaced, and in this situation, the lines of your ASCII art won't line up appropriately since each character takes up a different amount of space. The solution is simple -- change the JTextArea's Font to `Font.MONOSPACED`. e.g.,

```
myTextArea.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

This will allow the characters to line up correctly